# tmux always starts with `/bin/bash` instead of `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Tags: macos, bash, shell, tmux

No matter what I do, `tmux` will always use `/bin/bash` as its login shell.

I have set `$SHELL` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` which should work according to the man page of `tmux`. And `$SHELL` is definitely exported, as I have double-checked with `declare -x`.

What is the matter?

Comment: This link may help resolve the issue (just substitute the alternative path to bash for zsh) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214068/configure-tmux-to-use-zsh